# How to input "P1" into C if H returns text? google sheets

Tags: regex, if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

how would I auto-input text "P1" or "P2" or "P3" (priority 1,2,3) into column C if column B returns a certain condition from a list.
example: if Cell H1 = AD01A01, the script will find what priority list its in and change cell C1 to return the prioity.

The script or formula needs to be able to identify if cell A1 is a lower prioriry and chnage it to higher priority if the condtion is met (even if cell A1 was manualy edited)

Also i need to be able to keep the data validation drop down in place so cell A1 can changed manualy without removing any formula (if used)

[Auto Priority](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xW9AGQe_g092CXNh0taMarQmUfx0Aykf4cxohwT-ByI/edit#gid=0)

Comment: I think that your question lacks a lot of information in what you are trying to achieve, take a look at [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide more information so you can have a useful response. 
As for now I don't know what do you mean by P1, is this a literal text "P1". Also a sheet with an example of the expected behavior would be nice.

Comment: You have added a private file, is not accessible, make sure to make it public. Just to confirm you want to make the value of A1 = "P1" when B1 is blank or matches a text?

Comment: sheet is private

Comment: You can't use formula to active cells, because it Will be circular error. So please try to use trigger

Comment: i have changed the link so you can access it and have changed the decription so hopfully it explains it better

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=IF((B1<>"")*(B1="certain text"), "P1", )
```

with extended certain text:

```
=IF((B1<>"")*(B1="certain text 1")*(B1="certain text 2"), "P1", )
```

or if you got more values:

```
=IF((B1<>"")*(REGEXMATCH(B1, "text1|text2|text3"), "P1", )
```

and then if you want arrayformula, jyst wrap it into it and extend ranges...